# Does DHS support traditional Node.js or Java API?

Tags: marklogic

Does Data Hub Service supports traditional node.js and Java API?
Could we use for creating custom login UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It exposes REST-api's to which those clients can connect. Bear in mind thought that you might need to tunnel to a bastion first, or setup VPC peering to be able to reach the REST endpoints. Some documentation on the matter:

https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-hub-service-private-vpc/

and

https://docs.marklogic.com/cloudservices/aws/network/set-up-secure-network-dhs-aws.html

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation! Still can we delegate authentication to MarkLogic in DHS from custom login page? I would like to avoid application level authentication.

Comment: You can't use application-level authentication anyhow in DHS, but you can use LDAP for instance, via MarkLogic.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I meant was in case when deploying custom app separately on ec2 instance. So you mean custom app(on ec2) can leverage DHS's LDAP authentication instead of implementing app level authentication on the custom app side, am i correct?

Comment: Yes. You can run front-end and middle-tier in their own VPC, peer it with the DHS VPC, have the middle-tier pass through auth requests to a DHS rest api endpoint, and have DHS setup to use LDAP as external security source.